# Questions to OAuth consent screen - how to edit+support email+verification

Tags: oauth-2.0, oauth, google-oauth, google-developers-console

Some questions to OAuth Consent Screen:

1. Is any data that I input while configuring OAuth Consent Screen editable? For example if I decide to change my app's name, can I edit that?
2. Does the OAuth Consent screen need to be submitted/verified/published in order to use it to test features like achievements or leaderboards?
3. When choosing the support email, can I choose it from the list if I add that email to the project, or do I need to be logged in with that email and do the whole process from that account?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is any data that I input while configuring OAuth Consent Screen editable? For example if I decide to change my app's name, can I edit that?

Yes you can edit the consent screen on google cloud console for the project. The app will need to be verified again if you change things like name, description, or any of the URLS like privacy and home page.

> Does the OAuth Consent screen need to be submitted/verified/published in order to use it to test features like achievements or leaderboards?

Not sure on this one.  My guess would be no if your just testing something it doesn't need to be verified until you are in production.

> When choosing the support email, can I choose it from the list if I add that email to the project, or do I need to be logged in with that email and do the whole process from that account?
> oauth-2.0.

You need to create a google user with that email address. then you can add that  user to your project and set them as the support email.  They need to have access to the project you cant just add anyone.

Comment: thanks for all the answers! maybe you also know an answer to yet another question that popped in my head: is it possible to delete the OAuth consent screen and create a completely new one? I;m considering creating a placeholder just for testing purposes but not sure if I can delete it, to replace it with a new, proper one

Comment: You should have two different projects in google cloud console. One for test development and the other for production.   Ones the Consent screen has been created it cant be removed.   And any changes in a verified consent screen need to be reverified.

Comment: Remember to accept the answer if it helped you. It will also increase your rep.  Welcome to stack

Comment: thanks! sorry to bomb you with questions but one last one - if I set up a test project on google cloud platform and generate the test oauth consent screen there, I have to then link it to Google Play Game Services in the configuration section. Is it possible to later switch the linked OAuth Consent Screen to the proper one? Or is it better to also make a test app on Google Play Console?

Comment: I think you should open a new question.  Im not the best person to chat with about Play console.    Always open a new question really.   More questions give you more rep :)